CS undergrad query about DS
why is learning DS so ambigious .you dont truly know what should you learn to actually do DS .web dev say has  a clear path learn html css js and you can make something .i am a cs undergrad just want to get your help on how can i start learning DS and actually be a ace at it in a year provided a scenario that i am a hustler i can give it 16 hours  a day .just need direction and proper map .i just think  most of you guys have been through  what i am currenty going through.Thanks for reading .Take care.

“Data science” as a distinct term is fairly new, especially compared to related fields like statistics, computer science, and economics. Consequently, it is not totally clear what constitutes data science. Sure, there is a scope on this Stack, but this is just one venue. Not everyone has to agree with how this Stack defines data science.
Is data science statistics? Is data science statistics done on a computer? Is data science different from data analysis. Is data science machine learning? Is data science deep learning? Is data science about predicting? Is data science software development? Is data science SQL management? Other data management? Data visualization? People who know how to work with computers?
Not everyone is going to agree on the answers to those questions, so various shops have different requirements, depending on the exact work they do and the skills by existing employees. If they already have a bunch of statisticians, they probably seek other skillsets in a new hire. If a shop lacks a statistician, such skills might be emphasized. If the statisticians lack background in modern deep learning, such skills might be emphasized. If the SQL administrators have no idea how to draw insights or even present some basic insights to management, someone with a background in data visualization might be desired.
Combine this with the perception that data scientists make a lot of money (whatever that means) and that data scientists being tremendous value, and tons of people want to be and hire data scientists, whether that label accurately describes the skills of the perspective employee or the tasks performed in job opening.
Ergo, there is not a clear path to becoming a data scientist, what degree(s) to earn or what skills to acquire.
